# 500 Internal Server Error When Cloning Git Repo On LAMP CentOS VPS

Tags: linux, git, ssh, centos

Cloning or pulling a git repo using ssh (Laravel App) causes an internal server error when browsing to a php file. Manually adding an index.php file and echoing something works fine.

I believe it is a file permission error but this only occurs on this server. Every other server I clone to works off the bat.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, how do you expect us to help if you don't att the details that might be relevant? Like for example the file system permissions, if you already suspect that is the issue? We cannot _guess_ them, you see?

Comment: I don't know what details to give. I know changing the permissions to 0755   for directories and files to 0644 but they are already set to this after the clone.

Comment: If you get an error 500 form an http server the first thing to do is to take a look into its error log file. You also take a look at the file permissions. Keep in mind that not only the permission code, but also user and group account of the files are relevant. Then also remember that not only the file permissions themselves have to comply, but also the permission to all directories up in the hierarchy so that the server process can actually reach the files in question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The errors generated are as follows: http://pastebin.com/8qgbebHG

When I recursively changed the folder permissions to 0755 permissions on the folder give-kitchen and then again only on files to 0644 the error is gone. I dont really want to have to change the file permissions every pull. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: This is a question of the account and environment you use for your git workflow. Take care to set user group and the file mask (umask) such that newly created files and directories are accessible as required by the http server process. What you observe is a general effect of the way accounts, settings and commands play together in a unixoid system. You want to read about setting group membership of accounts, so called "suid bits" and umask settings.

Comment: Git was installed using the root account. I then clone the directory using the user account.  Is it just a case that I need to add the http server process (apache user on CentOS?) to the group I use to clone the repo?

Comment: Several alternatives. One is to grant group membership to the apache process account, but then you also have to take care to make all directories and files group-writable, that is what the umask is for. Or you could your users current group to that of the apache process account, then newly created files will belong to that group and the apache server can write without additional care (typically). Or you could use mentioned file system flags ("sticky bit") which will force newly created nodes to belong to a certain group... As always, unixoid systems are very mighty, offer many approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and doing these instructions fixed it

one must pay careful attention to the insecure permissions of user’s public_html folders.  The following commands will look in every user’s html folder and make the appropriate CHMOD to allow php to properly execute under SUPHP.  Don’t forget to also check for files owned by ‘nobody’ or ‘root’ — they will also fail with a 500 error.

```
find /home/*/public_html/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 # For directories
find /home/*/public_html/ -type f -not -name "*.pl" -not -name "*.cgi" -not -name "*.sh" -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644 # For files
find /home/*/public_html/ -type f -name "*.cgi" -print0 -o -name "*.pl" -print0 -o -name "*.sh" -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 # For CGI/Scripts
```

[chmod all files and folders](http://djlab.com/2009/06/cpanel-suphp-chmod-all-files-644-and-all-folders-755/)